# Bizarre Internet Explorer 9 issue - duplicating text in multiline textbox

Tags: internet-explorer-9, textarea

I have just found the most bizarre Internet Explorer issue I think I've ever seen, and have absolutely no idea how to get around it, so was hoping that maybe someone has seen something similar before and knows what causes it / how to fix it.

I have a multi-line textbox, as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDoctorNotes" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="8" Width="270"></asp:TextBox>
```

I noticed this morning that some of the words in this textbox were duplicated, and thinking I'd just made a mistake when typing it I clicked in the box to change the contents, and strangely the duplications disappeared, and it read as it should be. I have no "onclick" event on the textbox, though jquery is used when the contents are changed (so when I tab out of the box jquery flags up that some contents of the form have been changed). Thinking it was a one off rendering issue, I reloaded the page, and sure enough the same duplications reappeared, clicked in the box, they disappeared. Oddly the duplicated words weren't at the beginning or end of the contents, and weren't even all together, it just randomly duplicated them.

Tried it in Chrome, works perfect, no duplication.

As an example I've changed the contents to the following:

"the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".

I've put a breakpoint on the line that sets the contents of the textbox, and it shows the above, however, when the form loads it shows:

"the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy over the lazy dog".

If I click on it, it changes to read correctly.

When I had my actual notes in there earlier, it also duplicated the last word, but separately from the others, so in the above example it would have read:

"the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy over the lazy dog dog".

I'm running Internet Explorer 9. If I change to Internet Explorer 8 mode via the F12 button it fixes the issue, so it seems to be IE9.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this on XP IE8. The solution for me was to combine a bunch of different junk:

*remove all whitespace around the textarea and its container
*remove comments around the textarea, or in the page if you can
*If the textarea's hidden by default, populate its text ONLY on the action that shows it! This is imo the most important one.

Good luck, this bug was around back in IE7 and they never really fixed it.